# can Mule HTTP out-bound handler redirect requests?

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component

i am using http component of mule as a outbound to call a rest service which is sending a '307' redirect request , and HTTP endpoint is not handling the redirect request .
what i mean is, HTTP component is not handling the redirect request to another URL .like, other HTTP clients like Apache etc are handling !

is it the expected behavior of the end point or am i doing anything wrong .

`INFO  2015-01-06 15:13:23,193 [[test].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.04] org.mule.transport.http.HttpsClientMessageDispatcher: Received a redirect, but followRedirects=false. Response code: 307 Temporary Redirect`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the **followRedirects** flag of the outbound endpoint to *true*.

```
<http:outbound-endpoint followRedirects="true" .... />
```