# Java WebService call ends with "Received a redirect, but followRedirects=false"

Tags: java, web-services, mule, cxf, mule-esb

I have a webservice client generated from SoapUI and Apache CXF component. When I run it at Mule ESB server I receive the following error:

```
org.mule.transport.http.HttpClientMessageDispatcher - Received a redirect, but followRedirects=false. Response code: 401 Unauthorized
```

Mule Flow looks like this:
[image: flow scheme]

The interesting fact here is that when I run it locally from Anypoint Studio everything works fine. How can I allow my service client to handle redirections. Is there any other error? 
Here is my code:

```
URL wsdlURL = MPServiceService.WSDL_LOCATION;    
MPServiceService ss = new MPServiceService(wsdlURL, SERVICE_NAME);    
MPService port = ss.getDomino();

BindingProvider prov = (BindingProvider) port;
prov.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY,
        requestpath);    
prov.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY, username);
prov.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, password);

String result = port.webServiceFoo();
return result;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probem was caused by another application which had the following cxf config:

```
<cxf:configuration name="CXF_Configuration" initializeStaticBusInstance="true" enableMuleSoapHeaders="false"  doc:name="CXF Configuration"/>
```

We have changed **initializeStaticBusInstance="false"** so it looks like this:

```
<cxf:configuration name="CXF_Configuration" initializeStaticBusInstance="false" enableMuleSoapHeaders="false"  doc:name="CXF Configuration"/>
```

More info https://support.mulesoft.com/s/article/There-are-at-least-2-connectors-matching-protocol-https-when-using-CXF-generated-client

Answer (score 0):

It seems your error comes from the Mule app your URL is serving, not from the code above. When hitting your webservice, the Mule made a request inside a flow - most likely using the `http:request` or `http:outbound-endpoint` component - which caused an error, and this error is being returned by your web service.

Your Mule app is the problem, not the Java code above. See [can Mule HTTP out-bound handler redirect requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27796215/can-mule-http-out-bound-handler-redirect-requests) for how to solve your Mule issue.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I see that http:outbound-endpoint componente is currenty Deprectated. Is there any other way to solve it?

Comment: The same parameter exists also on the recent `http:request` (I edited accordingly). You'll probably have to update the Mule app you are requesting. How to solve will depend on why exactly this issue arise in the flow on which the requester is configured. Is it expected to have a redirect? Should it be followed? etc.

Comment: Well, I see that property but I can't figure out how to use it. I've updated  my question with the flow scheme. I have only http listener and java component that calls the WS. Where should I add the http-request?

Comment: It's not on your client flow you should configure the http:request, it's on the server-side on the web service you are calling. The error you are showing is returned by the WS, right? What do you mean by "run it locally from anypoint" and how does it differ from the way you run it and obtain the error?

Comment: My flow have a webservice consumer (Call Soap WS component). This component call a service that is located on the external server. When I run my flow locally everything is ok - authentication is ok and I receive a correct result. But when I deploy my project to Mule server and run the flow remotely I receive 401 error and the information in the log file: org.mule.transport.http.HttpClientMessageDispatcher - Received a redirect, but followRedirects=false. Response code: 401 Unauthorized

Comment: Can you paste the entire log related to your deployment until the issue occur? How do you deploy your app?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158175/discussion-between-pierre-b-and-dj-universe).